# Flutter app gives bunch of "could not build module" errors for IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, build

I have a working android app written in [flutter](/questions/tagged/flutter) which works fine. When I want to build it for ios using [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode) I am getting a bunch of "module could not build" errors with a "failed to emit pre-compiled header xxx" error. I did days of searching on google and StackOverflow and tried different approaches. None solved the problem.

Error log:

```
failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/emrecaglar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fxwxdylmxkcpzxeqrhwvvfdkrcwt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_3CL9TF27LCUZ1-clang_39V4VM58ZMBMS.pch' for bridging header '/Users/emrecaglar/Documents/Development/Projects/itirafcom/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CABase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CABase.h:16:10 could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Headers/CFNetwork.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Headers/CFNetwork.h:18:10 could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:20:10 could not build module 'Dispatch'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGBase.h:12:10 could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/Headers/CMBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/Headers/CMBase.h:167:10 could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudioTypes.framework/Headers/CoreAudioBaseTypes.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudioTypes.framework/Headers/CoreAudioBaseTypes.h:18:10 could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/CoreAudioTypes.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/CoreAudioTypes.h:4:10 could not build module 'CoreAudioTypes'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Headers/CoreImageDefines.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Headers/CoreImageDefines.h:17:10 could not build module 'CoreGraphics'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Headers/CTFontTraits.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Headers/CTFontTraits.h:14:10 could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Headers/CVBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Headers/CVBase.h:30:10 could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:63:10 could not build module 'os_object'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/Headers/EAGL.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/Headers/EAGL.h:8:10 could not build module 'Foundation'

/Users/emrecaglar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fxwxdylmxkcpzxeqrhwvvfdkrcwt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h
/Users/emrecaglar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fxwxdylmxkcpzxeqrhwvvfdkrcwt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:8:9 could not build module 'UIKit'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10 could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

/Users/emrecaglar/Documents/Development/Projects/itirafcom/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h
/Users/emrecaglar/Documents/Development/Projects/itirafcom/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:10:9 could not build module 'Flutter'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Headers/ImageIOBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Headers/ImageIOBase.h:16:10 could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Headers/IOSurfaceBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Headers/IOSurfaceBase.h:36:10 could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

/Users/emrecaglar/Documents/Development/Projects/itirafcom/ios/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources/module.modulemap
/Users/emrecaglar/Documents/Development/Projects/itirafcom/ios/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources/module.modulemap:1:8 redefinition of module 'Firebase'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLTypes.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLTypes.h:8:9 could not build module 'Foundation'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/Headers/NSFileProviderDomain.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/Headers/NSFileProviderDomain.h:8:9 could not build module 'Foundation'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework/Headers/NSString+UserNotifications.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework/Headers/NSString+UserNotifications.h:8:9 could not build module 'Foundation'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/usr/include/os/object.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/usr/include/os/object.h:114:9 could not build module 'ObjectiveC'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h:28:10 could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:9 could not build module 'Foundation'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/usr/include/os/workgroup_base.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.1.sdk/usr/include/os/workgroup_base.h:19:10 could not build module 'os_object'
```

Here are what I have tried so far and bunch of additional logs and outputs from my current setup.

So far, no luck. I appriciate any kind of suggestion. Thanks!

My local dev environment is:

> MacOS 13.0.1 (22A400) Ventura

> XCode version 14.1

```
%flutter --version
Flutter 3.3.10 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 135454af32 (7 days ago) • 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
Engine • revision 3316dd8728
Tools • Dart 2.18.6 • DevTools 2.15.0
```

```
%flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-arm, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

I have tried

1. "Reset Package Caches" and "Update to Latest Package versions"
2. Clean Derived folder
3. Removed the entire IOS folder of flutter and regenerated.
4. Cleaned podfile.lock and Pods folder and run "install pod"
5. Checked target ios version and it is ios 11 along the project
6. Commented out ios version on podfile as ios 11 to try.
7. I set "Enable Modules" (C and Objective-c) to false
8. Re-install Command Line Tools and XCode

and I was expecting to build the IOS project in XCode without and error.

Answer (score 0):

Also experiencing this exact issue. My app is released on the appstore. However after adding Firebase SDK to allow push notifications I now have a bridging header issue coupled with 25 could not build modules...

You haven't provided enough information here but if you have done what I did which is add firebase-sdk-ios using Swift package manager and you also have Firebase Core in your pub spec yaml XCode is going to hate on you for it.

You must remove the pubspec imports, you cant import the Firebase from two different directions.

I solved my problem because I'm using a separate code library for my IOS app. SO I can remove all the dependencies for registering and using an android FCM Token. I am now getting my FCM Token in the appdelegate.swift and passing the token into flutter with a method channel.

I can provide more information and code examples if this is your problem. However if not I'm afraid my IOS knowledge is limited as I'm predominately an Android developer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33887218)